# Unity Slerp Rotation Moved back to original rotation - not working correctly with negative numbers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object that has its orientation turning when a keyboard button is pressed in the appropriate direction (up,down,left, right).

After turning I have made a reset script linked to a button which resets the position of the object back to the original orientation. This is works fine and the game object orientates back.

The problem I am having involves an if statement that reads if the value of the game object's orientation is the same as it was originally over a period of time. This if statement enables other buttons in the scene again. Now through some watching of the the orientation is doing I have noticed the if statement will react properly if the orientation values are all positive numbers, however if any are negative numbers ; well it won't enable the other buttons again.

I have added a cut down version of the script.

```
void Update()
{
    if (_reset)
        if (kinder.transform.localRotation == originalRotationValue)
        {
            AnimationLerp(true, false);
        }
        else
        {
            kinder.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(kinder.transform.localRotation, originalRotationValue, speed);
            kinder.transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(kinder.transform.localPosition, startTime, speed);
        }
}
// Update is called once per frame
public void ResetOnClick()
{
    AnimationLerp(false, true);
}

void AnimationLerp(bool A, bool B)
{
    Dialyser.GetComponent<RotationByMouseDrag>().enabled = A;
    PurposeButton.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = A;
    FocusButton.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = A;
    _reset = B;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare Quaternions, it would be best to measure the angle between those Quaternions and check whether it is below some threshold.

```
private const float OrientationThreshold = 5f; // degrees

if (Quaternion.Angle(kinder.transform.localRotation, originalRotationValue) < OrientationThreshold)
    ; // goal reached
```

If your code were different I'd warn you to use `FixedUpdate()` to prevent overshooting, but as you are lerping towards the goal overshooting is not possible.

You may want to test target position as well, you can do this just as easily:

```
private const float PositionThreshold = .05f; // units

if (Vector3.Distance(kinder.transform.localPosition, originalPositionValue) < PositionThreshold)
    ; // goal reached
```

Just combine the two checks and you're good.

Comment: I cannot fault this at all and you have learnt me something new Thomas so much appreciated.  I will be using this more in future.  Thank you for all of this and have a good day.